# Please help with this issue with my plant!

Tags: diagnosis

My curry leaf plant which is potted in a 10 inch container with store bought potting mix has leaves which have got brown on the edges and dry. Also, the newest branch has very light coloured leaves. The plant is in Delhi, India and is getting 3 hours of hot sunlight and temperature is 30~41 degrees celsius. Please help diagnose the issue with my plant. I have posted several times earlier but have got no response.
[image: Full plant]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It looks like it might not be getting enough sunlight, which makes sense because 3 hours of sun isn't very much for a part/full sun plant like a curry tree. Also the wilty leaf edges make me wonder if it's getting enough water, the soil certainly looks dry.

Comment: The soil is moist at the surface. One day I kept it in full sunlight for 7 hours and then I am seeing this, and it was not hardened off. So how should I proceed?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not an expert on curry leaf plants, but it looks like the problem is that it needs fertilizer to me (especially nitrogen), due to the yellowing leaves.